# Job Recommendation System

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, lstm, recommender-system, nlp

I am building a Job Recommendation System where I have Student Data for different subjects in Machine Learning(Data Viz, Python, Statistics, etc) and their skills from the resume. Need to Recommend jobs scraped from a reputed website.

Current thoughts- Using CF for finding similar students with similar skills and ranking them based on their performance in the subjects and then matching them with the scraped jobs for the relevant skills.

Based upon Job Titles- options are word2vec to find semantics from job titles, Lstms for semanctics etc.

Based upon Job's key skills- Can do direct strin matching and filter based upon Experience.

I want a good approach for my Problem.